# i have made an PNG to JPG converter in python.but when i open the file it says we don't support this file format

Tags: python, tkinter

```py
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image
from numpy.distutils.fcompiler import none

root = tk.Tk()

canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width=300, height=250, bg='azure3', relief='raised')
canvas1.pack()

label1 = tk.Label(root, text='File Conversion Tool', bg='azure3')
label1.config(font=('helvetica', 20))
canvas1.create_window(150, 60, window=label1)

im1 = None
def getPNG():
    global im1

    import_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    im1 = Image.open(import_file_path)


browseButton_PNG = tk.Button(text=" Import PNG File ",command=getPNG, bg='royalblue', fg='white' ,font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 130, window=browseButton_PNG)


def convertToJPG():
    global im1
    export_file_path = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.jpg')
    im1.save(export_file_path)


saveAsButton_JPG = tk.Button(text='convert PNG to JPG', command=convertToJPG,bg='royalblue', fg='white' ,font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 180, window=saveAsButton_JPG)

root.mainloop()
```

This the code and the app is opening fine and the app is changing the file from PNG to JPG.

But the jpg file is saying `file.jpg` it appears that we don't support this file format.

Please check the code and attached images:

[properties of the jpg file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQ435.png)

[actual app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XyhZg.png)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lI6F.png):[JPG file when opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lI6F.png)

Comment: Normally, `Image.save()` will use the format based on the file extension, so your code should work.  Anyway, try specify the format when saving: `im1.save(export_file_path, format="jpg")`.

Comment: Your code works fine in my Windows 7 running Python 3.8.3 with Pillow 7.1.2.  What is the application used to check the output JPG image?  Did you try to open the output JPG image in other image processing application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your code just changes the extension of the file from .png to .jpg and doesn't actually convert the file.

Try replacing the line `im1.save(export_file_path)` in `convertToJPG()` with these two lines:

```
im2 = im1.convert('RGB')
im2.save(export_file_path)
```